# C# Winforms "TileLayoutPanel"

Tags: c#, winforms, tiles, flowlayout

Our Application has a dashboard, which is basically optimized on a FullHD Resolution, allowing to show 4x3 (12) Widgets of equal size.

This is generally enough, cause every widget also has a "FullScreen" Page that can be viewed by clicking on "show more".

However, now there is a single widget, just showing reminders. Not really enough for designing a dedicated fullscreen view, but sometimes to much to be squeezed into a 450x250 Element...

So, I thought about doubling it in height - but Every Element is sitting inside a `flowlayoutpanel` - so equal height / width is required for a nice view...

Is there some advanced (3rd Party) `tilelayoutpanel`, which allows to allocate boxes (UserControls) of different sizes, without reinventing the wheel?

---

To answer the "unclear what you are asking" vote: I'm searching for a way to arrange "boxes" (Controls of different sozes) on an area given. Just like the Windows 10 Start Menu.  Multiples of a "base-Width" and "base-Height" would be fine ofc.

But layout should be "liquid", i.e. Occupy the most possible space, when resizing the containing window.

---

Problem of "FlowLayoutPanel":

[image]

Comment: You can use `TableLayoutPanel`. 

For each control you can set `ColumnSpan` and `RowSpan` in design time or at run-time.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thought about that, but when it comes down to resizing windows and regenerating the view, it is really awkward compared to the `flowlayoutpanel` which wraps content if required.

Comment: Nothing like that in the WinForms library.  Looking for recommendations is off-topic.

Comment: @LarsTech Ever Heard of 3rd-Party libs? - like whole Ribbon-Controlls or stuff like that? There's no difference in that. Who would design a "Ribbon" from the scratch, if there are frameworks available?

Comment: @LarsTech don't blame me for a question, blame yourself for a not-helpfull answer. I'm here for ages, more helping than asking, but statemants like yours are not really contributing...

Comment: Hmm, not sure I understand the hostility.  It's one of the close reasons -> "recommendations".  `Is there some advanced (3rd Party) tilelayoutpanel` is asking for a recommendation.  That's off-topic.

Comment: @LarsTech If that's a predefined close-reason, it should be removed. There is (imho) no Problem in asking for "Libraries that already do what is required". Don't Confuse that option with a question like: "Should I implement it like A or B?" (which is "asking for a recommendation")

Comment: "Should I implement it like A or B?" could potentially be closed for "primarily opinion-based".  `If that's a predefined close-reason, it should be removed.`: you should take that up on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @LarsTech: Done that: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380502/close-reason-on-stackoverflow-recommendation

Comment: Adding to what Reza Aghaei said: a TableLayoutPanel can be considered a Grid. Row and Columns can have a specific size. Let's say Pixels. If you build a Grid of rows and columns of 10 pixels each, you can then use the ColumnSpan and RowSpan to make controls fit the Grid in different ways, If your Controls have a size that is a multiple of 10... Plus, each Cell of the Grid can contain other containers. Another TableLayoutPanel or FlowLayoutPanel, for example. Maybe, a TLP with the same featurers of the Parent's (...)

Comment: (...) A typical use (which requires some *handling*) is the [Masonry effect](https://www.google.it/search?q=masonry+effect&tbm=isch&source=univ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfzO_2t9DgAhWusaQKHda_DKgQsAR6BAgEEAE&biw=1512&bih=864).

Comment: As you have a specific use case where you can specify the height/width relationship of the added controls, it should not be that difficult to define a custom layout engine's logic to achieve the desired effect.  see: [LayoutEngine Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.layout.layoutengine?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples)

Comment: @dognose TableLayoutPanel supports percentage based sizing for columns and rows. Doesn't percentage based sizing help? For example designing a 4x3 grid layout, it will always show the 4x3 grid in the window. But the content of the cells grows or shrinks. The content then should be designed (using dock and anchor) in a way which shows well in different sizes.

Comment: Another question: Do all the control have same Width?